# How can I count data2.length with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working with Facebook Graph API and facing two kind of arrays.
Can anybody tell me about what is the different between them?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data1 = ["apple", "orange", "coconut"];
    var data2 = {"apple", "orange", "coconut"};
</script>
```

What is the different between `[]` and `{}` in `json`?
Why do `data2.length` doesn't work?
How can I count data2.length with JavaScript??

Seems like off-topic but I need to know counting data2 length. Is there anyway?

Comment: The difference is that the first kind of array exists, while the second does not. The correct syntax for the second is `{ foo: "bar", baz: 42 }`. What you've got there is interpreted as something else and is not any sort of array.

Comment: Edited this question..
Is it Ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When we declare any `var` as a `[]`, it's an array of elements. It can be of single elements or array of objects. `data1` is an array of simple elements (like in your case, an array of strings). That's why you can get the length of `data1` successfully.
2. When you declare a variable as `{}` it means that you are declaring an object and not an array.

Answer (score 4):

In JSON [] represents an array of objects, while {} represents a collection of objects.
So [{}] would represent an array of a collection of objects.

You can refer http://www.json.org/ for more info

Answer (score 1):

**short answer: `{}` is used for object notation, while `[]` is used for arrays.**
I suggest before you work on external APIs master the basics of javascript first. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm following...!
If I were a Master of JavaScript, I need not to ask. :-D
You explained good in short.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[] is an array and {} is an object, so basically in the first case you will have data1[0]=apple, data1[1]=orange etc. and in the second case you will get data2.apple=undefined, data2.orange=undefined etc.

Answer (score 0):

First one is an array. Second one is a structure.

Look at the link below for further information.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm